# Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, locale, debian-based

I am seeing this error: "Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory"

It seems to be solved by running:

1. `export LC_ALL="C.UTF-8"`
2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: This question should have been formatted In a Q & A, not JUST an answer. Change the question, and answer your own question.

Comment: This question looks like it should be on superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com - it doesn't seem to be programming related.

Comment: @Quentin indeed, good call.

Comment: [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157124/250848) to a similar question on the Unix SE page.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/locale.gen, uncommenting the line:

en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
then running:

locale-gen